# Get Parse image without Picasso Lib and use ShowInfoWindow() Instead

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

Long story short: I am using picasso to get an image from parse, but downloaded item is not the correct image file. Can anyone provide an example for ShowInfoWindow()? I do not wish to use Picasso. I got this solution from other posts.

"infowindow is not showing the downloaded image because MapFragment renders the view into a Canvas and then draws that. What you're seeing in the info window aren't the views you created, but a "picture" or "screenshot" of them. You basically need to call showInfoWindow() again on the Marker object, and that will re-render the Canvas and your image will now be visible."

Can anybody please tell me How and where can I call ShowInfoWindow() on the marker object? I used picasso but Picasso does not return the correct file image. I understand that using Picasso has many advantages for memory usage but it simply isn't working. I do not wish to use picasso at this point. Here is my code for reference. Thank you.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());




                ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");
                if(searchType!=null && searchType.length()>0) {
                    ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(String type: searchType.split("\\|")) types.add(type);
                    query.whereContainedIn("icon", types);
                }
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();

                    for(ParseObject obj : objects){
                        if(obj.getParseFile("icon") !=null) {

                            ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                            icon.getLayoutParams().height = 800; // OR
                            icon.getLayoutParams().width = 800;

                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl()).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));

                        }
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: "but Picasso does not return the correct file image" -- then perhaps there is a bug in how you are determining the URL to use.

Comment: I am sure you are correct. The getParseFile method points to the column name "icon" but it returns the first icon it finds and not the icon from the selected  parse  tablerow. Do I need to reference it by id? maybe a TAG? How can I make sure I get the "icon" image.png file ?

Comment: Should I cache the image?

Comment: That is much more of a Parse question, and I do not use Parse. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time.

Comment: If you have any input on the ShowInfoWindow() instead of Picasso it would be great.

Comment: It's not "instead of". You wind up having to use both. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/ImagePopups/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/imagepopups/PopupAdapter.java (which needs a rewrite, but should still work).